# Jquery Mobile: Forcing refresh of content

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a big problem: I have a `listview` and each item links to page `#concorsi`. When I click on a link the URL become `#concorsi?numero=1` because I'm fetching the form number 1 from a JSON.

When I click the first time it's all OK. Each input is visualized with jQuery Mobile classes but if I come back and after go into the same link the code don't refresh. 
The header is well visualized but the content no. How can I force the refresh of the div content?

These are my JavaScript functions:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).bind( "pagebeforechange", function( e, data ) {
    // We only want to handle changePage() calls where the caller is
    // asking us to load a page by URL.

    if ( typeof data.toPage === "string" ) {
        // We are being asked to load a page by URL, but we only
        // want to handle URLs that request the data for a specific

        var u = $.mobile.path.parseUrl( data.toPage ),
            re = /^#concorso/;
        if ( u.hash.search(re) !== -1 ) {
            // We're being asked to display the items for a specific category.
            // Call our internal method that builds the content for the category
            // on the fly based on our in-memory category data structure.
            showConcorso( u, data.options);
            // Make sure to tell changePage() we've handled this call so it doesn't
            // have to do anything.
            e.preventDefault(); 
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

And `showConcorso()`L

```
function showConcorso( urlObj, options )
{
    document.getElementById('conccont').innerHTML="";
    var concorsoNum = urlObj.hash.replace( /.*numero=/, "" ),

        // Get the object that represents the category we
        // are interested in. Note, that at this point we could
        // instead fire off an ajax request to fetch the data, but
        // for the purposes of this sample, it's already in memory.
        concorso = obj.concorsi[ concorsoNum ],

        // The pages we use to display our content are already in
        // the DOM. The id of the page we are going to write our
        // content into is specified in the hash before the '?'.
        pageSelector = urlObj.hash.replace( /\?.*$/, "" );

    if ( concorso ) {
        // Get the page we are going to dump our content into.
        var $page = $( pageSelector ),

            // Get the header for the page.
            $header = $page.children( ":jqmData(role=header)" ),

            // Get the content area element for the page.
            $content = $page.children( ":jqmData(role=content)" ),
            $footer = $page.children( ":jqmData(role=footer)" );



        // Find the h1 element in our header and inject the name of
        // the category into it.
        $header.find( "h1" ).html(concorso['title']);

        markup=document.createElement('form');
        markup.setAttribute('action','#home');
        markup.setAttribute('method','POST');
        markup.id="concForm";
        markup.onchange="alert (test)";
        items=obj.concorsi[concorsoNum].elementi;

        for(field in items) {
            nest=items[field];
            nest=obj.campi[nest];
            switch(nest.type){
                case "free": markup.appendChild(createFree(nest));
                            break;
                case "text": markup.appendChild(createText(nest));
                            break;
                case "textarea": markup.appendChild(createTextArea(nest));
                            break;
                case "switch": markup.appendChild(createSwitch(nest));
                            break;
                case "switchcust": markup.appendChild(createSwitchCustom(nest));
                            break;
                case "slider": markup.appendChild(createSlider(nest));
                            break;
                case "select": markup.appendChild(createSelect(nest));
                            break;
                case "checkbox": markup.appendChild(createCheckbox(nest));
                            break;
                case "radio": markup.appendChild(createRadio(nest));
                            break;
                case "reset": markup.appendChild(createButton(nest));
                            break;
                case "submit": markup.appendChild(createButton(nest));
                            break;
            }
        }

        // Inject the category items markup into the content element.
        $content.html( markup );

        // Pages are lazily enhanced. We call page() on the page
        // element to make sure it is always enhanced before we
        // attempt to enhance the listview markup we just injected.
        // Subsequent calls to page() are ignored since a page/widget
        // can only be enhanced once.

        $page.page();


        // We don't want the data-url of the page we just modified
        // to be the url that shows up in the browser's location field,
        // so set the dataUrl option to the URL for the category
        // we just loaded.
        options.dataUrl = urlObj.href;

        // Now call changePage() and tell it to switch to
        // the page we just modified.
        $.mobile.changePage( $page, options );
    }
}
```

Comment: this question is also of relevance: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8946622/jquery-mobile-1-0-how-to-enhance-page-more-then-one-time/15302836#15302836

Answer (score 58, accepted):

To refresh the page user:

```
.trigger('create');
```

More Here:

- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/pages/page-scripting.html

> **Create vs. refresh: An important distinction** 
> Note that there is an important difference between the create event and refresh method that
>   some widgets have. The create event is suited for enhancing raw markup
>   that contains one or more widgets. The refresh method should be used
>   on existing (already enhanced) widgets that have been manipulated
>   programmatically and need the UI be updated to match.
>
> For example, if you had a page where you dynamically appended a new
>   unordered list with data-role=listview attribute after page creation,
>   triggering create on a parent element of that list would transform it
>   into a listview styled widget. If more list items were then
>   programmatically added, calling the listview’s refresh method would
>   update just those new list items to the enhanced state and leave the
>   existing list items untouched.

You can also refresh the listview like this:

```
$('#mylist').listview('refresh');
```

More Here:

- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/lists/docs-lists.html

> **Updating lists**
>  If you add items to a listview, you'll need to call the refresh() method on it to update the styles and create any
>   nested lists that are added. For example:
>
> ```
> $('#mylist').listview('refresh');
> ```
>
> Note that the refresh() method only affects new nodes appended to a
>   list. This is done for performance reasons. Any list items already
>   enhanced will be ignored by the refresh process. This means that if
>   you change the contents or attributes on an already enhanced list
>   item, these won't be reflected. If you want a list item to be updated,
>   replace it with fresh markup before calling refresh.

Refreshing Form Elements:

- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/forms/docs-forms.html

> **Refreshing form elements**
>  In jQuery Mobile, some enhanced form controls are simply styled (inputs), but others are custom
>   controls (selects, sliders) built from, and kept in sync with, the
>   native control. To programmatically update a form control with
>   JavaScript, first manipulate the native control, then use the refresh
>   method to tell the enhanced control to update itself to match the new
>   state. Here are some examples of how to update common form controls,
>   then call the refresh method:

Checkboxes:

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").prop("checked",true).checkboxradio("refresh");
```

Radios:

```
$("input[type='radio']").prop("checked",true).checkboxradio("refresh");
```

Selects:

```
var myselect = $("#selectfoo");
myselect[0].selectedIndex = 3;
myselect.selectmenu("refresh");
```

Sliders:

```
$("input[type='range']").val(60).slider("refresh");
```

Flip switches (they use slider):

```
var myswitch = $("#selectbar");
myswitch[0].selectedIndex = 1;
myswitch.slider("refresh");
```

Collapsible:

```
$('div[data-role=collapsible]').collapsible();
```

Comment: OMG man i Love u. I spent 2 days searching this answare. Thx a lot!

Comment: i have <div data-role="header" id="myheader"> in body which is empty. I want to programatically (dom.ready event) add the <h1> and the button (<a href="menu.html" data-icon="home"> ...). I'm doing this: var jqmHeader = '<a href="menu.html" data-icon="home" data-theme="b">home</a><h1>My Files</h1>'; $('#myheader').html(jqmHeader); $('#myheader').trigger('create'); IT DOES NOT WORK?

Comment: +1. Hi, Phill. The above is a very good explanation, what is missing, IMO, is the general way to refresh arbitrary markup. Let's say I have a custom component that contains a listview and a button (both jquery mobile widgets). Upon some data retrieval I do a DOM manipulation and I want to refresh the DOM... let's say I added another button and an element to the list. `trigger('create')` wouldn't work, would it?

Comment: How about adding a timestamp to the page id? Could that work? I assume that jQM would never see the same page twice.

Comment: is there a generic method for all `input` elements?  i'm restoring the saved state, and i need to refresh the elements without knowing what type they are.

Comment: I know this is old but I have a question related to this and I don't wanna open another question about the same. What if I want to refresh the whole content (all of the contained in the div with `data-role=content`) is there a way to perform this? if I call `create` it will trigger what I have on create event which is something different to what I want.