# jQuery mobile 1.0: how to enhance page more than one time

Tags: jquery-mobile

jQuery mobile 1.0

I change the content of the page, to put it simple:

```
//$page - is enhanced page.
$page.html('<div data-role="header">New Header</div>');
// I what it to be enhanced but $page.page(), $page.trigger('create'), $page.trigger('refresh') is not working
```

According to docs 'page()' used once, the second time it is ignored. So what is the way to enhance page elements after dynamically added?

I know how to enhance "listview" but what about other elements?

Comment: $page.html("<div data-role="header">New Header</div>"); syntax error? should be $page.html("<div data-role='header'>New Header</div>");

Comment: Yes, Its just for the sake of example.

Comment: Could you give a link to a demo or use http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally when you initialize (enhance) a page once, you then refresh it instead of trying to initialize it again.

I have not tried to enhance a whole page at once, I normally call each widget's refresh method:

```
$('#my-listview-id').listview('refresh');
```

So perhaps you can do that for the `page()` function as well:

```
$('#my-page-id').page('refresh');
```

## Update

I found this in the docs for Dynamically Created Pages (http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/pages/page-dynamic.html):

```
    // Pages are lazily enhanced. We call page() on the page
    // element to make sure it is always enhanced before we
    // attempt to enhance the listview markup we just injected.
    // Subsequent calls to page() are ignored since a page/widget
    // can only be enhanced once.
```

## Update

So what you're doing there is overwriting all the jQuery Mobile styles, but you don't have to be doing that. With your developer tools, inspect the HTML structure of an initialized header widget (or whatever widget you may want to update). The structure of the HTML will be different and you will be able to target certain elements to update things like: text, icons, shadows, etc.

Here is an example jQuery Mobile Header widget after initialization:

```
<div data-role="header" data-theme="f" class="ui-header ui-bar-f" role="banner">
    <h1 class="ui-title" tabindex="0" role="heading" aria-level="1">Content formatting</h1>
    <a href="../../" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="notext" data-direction="reverse" class="ui-btn-right jqm-home ui-btn ui-btn-up-f ui-btn-icon-notext ui-btn-corner-all ui-shadow" title="Home" data-theme="f">
        <span class="ui-btn-inner ui-btn-corner-all" aria-hidden="true">
            <span class="ui-btn-text">Home</span>
            <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-home ui-icon-shadow"></span>
        </span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Notice that if you want to update the icon for the button, or it's text, you can target `.ui-icon` or `.ui-btn-text` inside the Button widget: `$('.ui-header').children('.ui-btn').find('.ui-text').text('my new button text')`.

Comment: I changed my question. I tried your proposal: uncaught exception: no such method 'refresh' for page widget instance

Comment: @WHITECOLOR That's too bad, looks like they didn't include a whole page refresh method. Can you refresh individual widgets, like `listview`s, `slider`s, etc? I guess my question is, what widgets are you trying to refresh?

Comment: I didn't try refresh. To enhance listview I use listview(). But I need to enhance p and hX and other stuff.

Comment: @WHITECOLOR You can do that once, `listview()` is how to initialize the widget (`trigger('create')` does the same thing for all widgets) however you can't call that method again to refresh the widget, you have to call `listview('refresh')` on subsequent calls. If you call `listview()` on an already initialized `listview` widget you will get an error.

Comment: @WHITECOLOR Can you post some of your code? There are so many possibilities of things you are doing, I'd like to give you advice that actually pertains to your issue.

Comment: @WHITECOLOR I updated my answer, perhaps you can more carefully update the DOM when you need to, so that you don't remove any structure/styles that have been applied.

Comment: When this styles are applied? I thought that I can just redraw the page and enhanced it again.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
$('#pageId').trigger('create');
```

Docs:

- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/pages/page-scripting.html

> **Enhancing new markup** 
>   The page plugin dispatches a pagecreate event, which most widgets use to auto-initialize themselves. As long
>   as a widget plugin script is referenced, it will automatically enhance
>   any instances of the widgets it finds on the page.
>
> However, if you generate new markup client-side or load in content via
>   Ajax and inject it into a page, you can trigger the create event to
>   handle the auto-initialization for all the plugins contained within
>   the new markup. This can be triggered on any element (even the page
>   div itself), saving you the task of manually initializing each plugin
>   (listview button, select, etc.).
>
> For example, if a block of HTML markup (say a login form) was loaded
>   in through Ajax, trigger the create event to automatically transform
>   all the widgets it contains (inputs and buttons in this case) into the
>   enhanced versions. The code for this scenario would be:
>
> ```
> $( ...new markup that contains widgets... ).appendTo( ".ui-page" ).trigger( "create" );
> ```
>
> **Create vs. refresh:** *An important distinction* 
> Note that there is an important difference between the create event and refresh method
>   that some widgets have. The create event is suited for enhancing raw
>   markup that contains one or more widgets. The refresh method should be
>   used on existing (already enhanced) widgets that have been manipulated
>   programmatically and need the UI be updated to match.
>
> For example, if you had a page where you dynamically appended a new
>   unordered list with `data-role=listview` attribute after page
>   creation, triggering create on a parent element of that list would
>   transform it into a listview styled widget. If more list items were
>   then programmatically added, calling the listview’s refresh method
>   would update just those new list items to the enhanced state and leave
>   the existing list items untouched.

UPDATE:

Can you try this

```
$page.html('<div data-role="header">New Header</div>');
$("div:jqmData(role='header')").trigger('create');
```

Comment: Could you edit your question and give a little more example code?

Comment: Yes but maybe that is work only on elements not on a whole page

Answer (score 2):

After struggling with this myself for some time I finally found a way to trick jQuery Mobile into re-enhancing:

```
$('#your-page').data({mobilePage: null}).page();
```

You won't find this in the docs anywhere, but they check `mobilePage` attached to the element via jQuery's `.data()` to see if it has already been enhanced or not.

I don't know whether or not this will have side-effects. It hasn't for me, but I'm using backbone for routing. You could try storing the value of `mobilePage` first, then using hack, then set `mobilePage` back.

Another option I [found here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/2703) is to use:

```
$('#your-page').trigger('pagecreate');
```

Someone commented that will cause back buttons to break.

If you're only updating the content section of the page then `$('#your-page').trigger('create');` will work.