# Changing JQuery Mobile data-theme dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I want to map a tap event to a function that changes the data-theme of a specific element in my document.  It looks something like this:

```
$(document).delegate("#item1", "tap", function() { 
        $("#item1").attr("data-theme", "e");
    });
```

So far, it kind of works correctly.  In the source code I can see it changing the attribute.  However, it doesn't get re-rendered on the document and everything appears to the stay the same.  Do I have to reload the document or is there a way to make it dynamically update?

Comment: Possible duplicate [of this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8357910/2049063)

Comment: It depends on that item you want to change. Each widget have a different way. Post your markup.

Answer (score 2):

First use .on and vclick instead of delegate and tap.
You can read on vclick [here](http://api.jquerymobile.com/vclick/), read on .on [here](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

You need to trigger refresh event, than jquery mobile will apply styling to that element again, for example if you change a list view, you can do this

```
$("#listview").listview('refresh')
```

In case you want styling changed on an element that has no refresh event, you can trigger page create event on the whole page, that will refresh everything.

```
$('#pageid').trigger('create')
```

Check here to see which elements have [refresh event](http://api.jquerymobile.com/?s=refresh)