# Collapse all form items JQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

Using J Query mobile 1.4.0

I have a form that has many expandable elements with multiple check boxes. When I click my refresh button I can clear all the users selections, however the different field sets remain **expanded**. I could refresh the page however I don't think that is a smooth option. Other than writing JS for each field set is there a method to reload the form or collapse all form elements?

[A good example for a list view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8357756/jquery-mobile-forcing-refresh-of-content) However this is for individual lists. I will need this code to apply to all form elements (collapsible fieldsets)

Comment: `$("[data-role=collapsible]").collapsible("collapse");` this will collapse.

Comment: @Omar If you put this into an answer I will accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To *collapse* or *expand* a collapsible programmatically, use `.collapsible()` widget with `collapse` or `expand` arguments.

```
/* collapse */
$(".selector").collapsible("collapse");

/* expand */
$(".selector").collapsible("expand");
```